# Remove participent from call while ringing Twillio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I want to remove participant from conference call. My case is call the multiple participants in a conference call at once. If any one first pick the call then disconnect the call from all other participants. I want to do this during ringing. Like first pick the call and others are still ringing I want to disconnect all ringing calls.

```html
 foreach ($participants as $participantPhoneNumber) {
    $conferenceOptions = ['startConferenceOnEnter' => true, 'endConferenceOnExit' => true];

    $dial = $response->dial('');
    $dial->conference($conferenceName, $conferenceOptions);
    
    $toPerson = "client:" . $participantPhoneNumber . "?typeOfCall=" . $typeOfCall . "&minimumMinutes=" . $minimumMinutes . "&language=" . $language . "&speciality=" . $speciality;

    $participant = $twilio->conferences($conferenceName)->participants->create("client:".$from, $toPerson, [
        "conferenceStatusCallback" => "http://****/**/**/status-callback.php",
        "conferenceStatusCallbackEvent" => "start end join leave mute hold modify speaker announcement",
        "conferenceStatusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
        "beep" => "false",
    ]);
}

    
$conferences = $twilio->conferences->read([
    "status" => "in-progress",
    "friendlyName" => $conferenceName,
]);

foreach ($conferences as $conference) {
    $participantsIDs = $twilio->conferences($conference->sid)->participants->read([], 20);
    foreach ($participantsIDs as $record) {
      //need to remove/disconnect all other participants that are still ringing if one already picked the call. 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The outcome you are seeking can be achieved using the [Dial verb with the Number noun](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number). It is not necessary to use a Conference.

> You can use up to ten  nouns within a  verb to
> simultaneously call all of them at once. The first call to pick up is
> connected to the current call and the rest are hung up. For each
>  noun you can specify what call progress events you want to
> receive webhooks for.

If you must use a Conference, you could redirect the first person who answered into a Conference.

In either method, you will need to deal with voicemails as it could appear that a person answered when it was actually a voicemail.

A more reliable approach would be to have all workers in a Conference, know that they are available, and then connect the available worker to the call. You can do this with or without [Taskrouter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter).